# How to close component using "back button" on mobile?

Tags: angular, popstate

I created profile component look like popup. The component can be display on every page (it's not dependent on routing). I wanted to close it was a "back" button on smartphone, so I used **HostListener** annotation with *window:popstate*. It works, but if I click back button ProfileComponent is closing, but also browser goes to the previous page. I tried fix that, using *preventDefault()*:

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keydown.escape')
closeProfile(event?: any) {
    if(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    this.store.dispatch(new layoutActions.CloseProfileAction());
}
```

but still doesn't work. Is there a way to overwrite *back* button action?

Answer (score 1):

The popstate event is not cancelable (as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate). So preventDefault is not doing anything in this case.

But if you want to stay on the page, virtually preventing the back button and just close the Profile popup you can do the following.

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keydown.escape')
closeProfile(event?: any) {
    history.go(1);
    this.store.dispatch(new layoutActions.CloseProfileAction());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button will lead to a pop in the history state.

So, what you can do is to add a "modal state" to the history stack after the modal is opened:

```js
  history.pushState({ modal: true }, '');
```

Than when the back button gets pressed, instead of poping the state of the previous page (and going back to it) this "modal state" will be the one poped and there will be no change in the current loaded page.

The following code shows how to do this using `ngx-boostrap` modal and can be easilly adapted for other modal implementations:

Online demo: https://angular12-bootstrap-bkyuq7.stackblitz.io/

Stackblitz source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-bkyuq7

Component typescript:

```js
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  private modal?: NgbModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event: any): void {
    console.log('back button pressed');
    this.modal?.close();
  }

  openBootstrapModal(modal: any): void {
    this.modal = this.modalService.open(modal);
    this.pushModalStateIntoHistory();
    this.modal.closed.subscribe(() => {
      this.modal = undefined;
    });
  }

  private pushModalStateIntoHistory(): void {
    history.pushState({ modal: true }, '');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="openBootstrapModal(demoModal)">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <ng-template #demoModal let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
      My Modal
      <button (click)="modal.dismiss()">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Modal content.</div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

For the sake of completeness, one may consider poping the `modal state` from the history stack when the `ngOnDestroy` method is invoked for the component:

```js
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.modal) {
      this.modal.close();
      this.popModalStateFromHistory();
    }
  }

  private popModalStateFromHistory(): void {
    if (window.history.state.modal) {
      history.back();
    }
  }
```